# Neweywest test in R

Tags: r, time-series, t-test, neweywest, hac

Portfolio analysis is being conducted using R.
We use the `neweywest` function belonging to the sandwich package, and the brief description is as follows.

```r
j <- lm(Y ~ 1)    
coeftest(j, vcov.=neweywest (j, adjust=T, prewhite=F))
```

How do I apply lag in `neweywest` test?
There are five portfolios in the same time series and each portfolio contains 200 months of data.
According to the rule of thumb, m=0.75*T^(1/3), so m is 4.38, and if floor is applied, it is 4. That is, since lag=m-1, is it right to apply lag=3?
Or do I have to apply lag = 0?

Is it the same when the regression coefficient by Fama-Macbeth cross-sectional regression analysis is expressed as neweywest-test?

Answer (score 1):

The lag in `NeweyWest()` (and also in `kernHAC()`) is selected automatically by default. Note that both of these do not apply simple rules of thumb but the procedures by Newey & West (1994, *Review of Economic Studies*) and Andrews (1991, *Econometrica*), respectively. So you don't have to do this manually unless you believe that the methods above do not work appropriately in your setting. For more details see:

- [`?NeweyWest`](https://sandwich.R-Forge.R-project.org/reference/NeweyWest.html)
- [`?kernHAC`](https://sandwich.R-Forge.R-project.org/reference/weightsAndrews.html)
- [`vignette("sandwich", package = "sandwich")`](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v011.i10)